# Validation error while trying to add Firebase token in Gitlab CI environment variable

Tags: gitlab-ci, firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

I want to add the token that I generated in firebase-tools using `firebase login:ci` to Gitlab CI. I went to `Settings -> CI/CD -> Variables` and added the environment variable with the key as `FIREBASE_TOKEN`. 

However I get:

```
Validation failed: 
- Variables value is invalid.
```

The value I gave is a 25 digit key generated by Firebase CLI as mentioned above.  
What is wrong in this and what must I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer myself. Gitlab doesn't allow certain characters, such as `-` or `/` as the value for the environment variables. So I split the key into 2 environment variables.

**EDIT #1:** The problem was because I had the option 'Mask' turned on. So turned it off and I was able to give the whole key as a single variable. Voila!